# How to add existing SQL Server database to app_data folder of asp.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I have an existing database in SQL Server. I am trying to create an asp.net mvc project around this db.

For this purpose I need to add the db to app_data folder of asp.net MVC project

How do I achieve this?

Note:

The SQL Server is in another system and I do not have rights to install SQL Server Express on my machine as well :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add `app_data` directory or install SQL Express on your machine. All you need is a connection string allowing you to connect to the remote database.

```
Data Source=NameOfDbServer;Database=DatabaseName;User ID=User;Password=PWD;Trusted_Connection=False
```

Once you have the connection string you can start querying the database. The way you do this will depend primary on the technology you would like to use: [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET), [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), [LINQ To Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx), [plain old ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021.aspx), ...

Comment: do I need to add the connection string in web.config or any other file?

Comment: Externalizing the connection string in the `connectionStrings` section of the `web.config` is a good idea.